# How do I know if I'm being hacked?

Tags: php, apache-http-server, security, lamp

I'm building a small site on a LAMP server and hadn't logged in for a few days. I logged in today to make some changes and after checking the error log I can see that I've had the following error every 20 minutes or so for the last 2 days:

```
[Tue Jan 10 17:35:49.638900 2023] [php:error] [pid 613684] [client 34.210.246.88:16546] script '/var/www/myfirstsite.com/public_html/.\\login.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Then this afternoon intermittently I get

```
[Tue Jan 10 10:26:34.458025 2023] [core:error] [pid 613686] [client 152.89.196.211:40956] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh)
```

And then

```
[Tue Jan 10 17:54:40.408131 2023] [php:error] [pid 613688] [client 152.89.196.211:41694] script '/var/www/myfirstsite.com/public_html/.\\login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://myip:myforwardingport/index.php?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21
[Tue Jan 10 18:20:26.710678 2023] [php:error] [pid 613685] [client 130.61.143.194:46704] script '/var/www/myothersite.com/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://myothersite.com/wp-login.php
```

I'm assuming this is someone trying to get into my server but I literally know nothing about cyber, so it might also be just a random error, but it's not me making request to these pages that don't exist.

I'm not super worried since this is just a Server and website I've built to teach myself how to do webdev and it's all backed up remotely, and as far as I can tell nothing has changed in the config/site file.

But can some explain?

Comment: Looks like some automated script that's looking for open exploits.  Your logs appear to indicate that your server is correctly returning an error.  This doesn't guarantee that your server *can't* be compromised, just that these attempts are correctly failing.

Comment: Right, atleast I know I'm not crazy or an idiot. Do you have a resource you can recommend where I can brush up on this kind of attack? I know it's impossible to prevent it entirely but it's also a little scary that my little site is getting this kind of attention and I suppose it's a good time to start learning.

Comment: well, its not precisely a kind of attack. they are looking to see if you have something they know to be vulnerable, and if they find it, that is when they attempt to exploit the vulnerability (using whatever means are appropriate to exploit that particular vuln). scanning for vulnerable systems is pretty much universal. all you need to know is how to detect that the vulnerability is present. the scary thing is that if they do find a vulnerable page, you are unlikely to get an error message about the request.

Comment: How do I look for vulnerabilities in my own setup? Sorry for the basic questions I'm basically self teaching.

Answer (score 2):

You have a valid question about hardening your site for vulnerabilities. You could try an online tool to evaluate vulnerabilities as a start, *after* you've followed security recommendations for LAMP, such from [TecAdmin](https://tecadmin.net/security-tips-for-lamp-stack-on-linux/), [RoseHosting](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-secure-your-lamp-server/) and [Linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/securing-your-lamp-stack/). A few sites are [Pentest Tools](https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/website-scanner) and [ImmuniWeb](https://www.immuniweb.com/websec/).

**N.B.** Pen testing *invites* an attack... be sure you research the tool for safety before testing.

Comment: thank you for the above, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Instream, did that *answer* your question?